# Method operating on container: hardcode the container type, or use generic template iterators?

Tags: c++, templates, api-design

I have code where, conceptually, my input is some container of `Foo` objects. The code "processes" these objects one by one, and the desired result is to fill up a container of `FooProduct` result objects.

I only need a single pass through the input container. The "processing" is stateful (this isn't an `std::transform()`) and the number of result objects is independent of the number of input objects.

Offhand, I could see two obvious ways to define the API here.

The easiest way to do this is to hardcode a specific type of container. For example, I could decide I'm expecting `vector` parameters, e.g.:

```
void ProcessContainerOfFoos(const std::vector<Foo>& in, std::vector<FooProduct>&out);
```

But, I don't really have any reason to limit client code to a particular type of container. Instead of constraining the parameter types specifically to `vector`, I could make the method generic and use iterators as template parameters:

```
/**
 * @tparam Foo_InputIterator_T An input iterator giving objects of type Foo.
 * @tparam FooProduct_OutputIterator_T An output iterator writing objects 
 *                                     of type FooProduct.
 */
template<typename Foo_InputIterator_T, typename FooProduct_OutputIterator_T >
void ProcessContainerOfFoos(Foo_InputIterator_T first, Foo_InputIterator_T last,
                     FooProduct_OutputIterator_T out);
```

I'm debating between these two formulations.

### Considerations

To me, the first code seems to me to be "easier" and the second seems "more correct":

- Non-template types make the signature clearer; I don't need to explain in the documentation what types to use and what the constraints on the template parameter are.
- Without templates I can hide the implementation in the .cpp file; with templates I'll need to expose the implementation in a header file, forcing client code to include anything I need for the actual processing logic.
- The templated version feels like it expresses my intention more clearly, because I'd rather be indifferent to what container type is used.
- The templated version is more flexible and testable - for example, in my code I might be using some custom data structure `MySuperEfficientVector` , but I'd still be able to test `MyFooProcessor` without any dependency on the custom class.

Beyond subjective choice given these considerations, **is there a major reason to choose one of these over the other?** Likewise, **is there a better way to construct this API which I'm missing?**

Comment: I personally would use the template version but I would return a `std::vector<FooProduct>` by value from the function to take advantage of move semantics.

Comment: @NathanOliver: do you mean like `template<typename Foo_InputIterator_T> std::vector<FooProduct> ProcessContainerOfFoos(Foo_InputIterator_T first, Foo_InputIterator_T last);`  ? I'm not clear on what the advantage here would be. In what way is moving the vector better than using an output iterator?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.  The reason I suggest this is to save steps on the caller of the function.  If you use an output iterator then the user need to create the vector and then call you function and pass an iterator to the function from the vector.  If you supply a vector return then the user could declare the vector and initialize it to the function which will make it RAII compliant. `std::vector<FooProduct> foo = ProcessContainerOfFoos(bar.begin(), bar.end());`.  Since we can use move semantics on return by value there is no performance hit for doing this.

Comment: @NathanOliver but then you lock the output into also being a vector, which is annoying. I personally would go with the full iterator option...you can skip reinitializing with an insert iterator.

Comment: @IdeaHat If he wants to offer that flexibility I totally agree with going with the full iterator option.

Comment: I would also return the output vector instead of passing a non-const reference. But only in the hard-coded version. And I would return output iterator past the last element from the template version.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the considerations that you've already listed:

- The template version allows the client code to pass any iterator
  range, for example a sub-range or reverse iterators, not just an entire container from begin to end.
- The template version allows passing value types other than `Foo`. For this to be useful, the processing must be generic of course.
- If the template works with only specific value type and the user tries to use iterators to wrong type, the error message might not be very descriptive of their mistake. If this is a concern, you can give the user a better error using type traits: `static_assert(std::is_same<Iter::value_type, Foo>::value, "I want my Foo");` Until concepts proposal is added to the standard, there is no good way to communicate the requirements of a template type in the signature to the user.

There is also the option to provide both functions. The hard coded one can delegate to the templated version. This gives you the advantages of both versions at the expense of bloating your api.

Comment: Very good points. I'm actually specifically interested in cases where I *know* exactly what class `Foo` is, and rely on it; if I want a generic type then certainly I want generics. What's intriguing me here is what to do when I want a *specific* type but a *generic* container.

Comment: @Ziv nothing *needs* to be done to the template when you know what value type to expect. If the template can't possibly work with any other type, then simply document that to the user. If a user tries to use invalid type, the error message might not be very descriptive though. If that's a concern, you may use something like `static_assert(std::is_same<Iter::value_type, Foo>::value, "I want my Foo");` for a better error.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If this function is going to be used with vectors for the time beeing why bother?

I suggest doing templated version only when it becomes necessary. Predicting such things in advance is hard.